# how can I connect to a server throught a firewall?

Tags: networking, firewall, network-attached-storage

I am trying to make a datbase connection from the **Server A** to the **Server B** , the Server B can only reached throught a network, that has its gateway on a firewall (it distributes internet and all other network things) , which is the best way to connect? Do I have to work with a NAS or creating a kind of VPN with my firewall??

Which is the best option?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think having a VPN connection is overkill. Can't you simply make a firewall exception and forward the port the DB uses from the firewall to server B?

Comment: forward like a NAS ???

Comment: If Server A Wants to connect to Server B, lets say over port 3306, and Server B is behind a firewall, you need to set a rule on the firewall that any connections using port 3306 be forwarded to Server B's IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, if you want two machines in different locations to be able to consistently talk to each other, establishing a VPN tunnel between the locations is a good approach. It not only provides the connectivity you need, but it provides security by encrypting all traffic between the two locations. If you only forwarded ports, your database network traffic would be sent unencrypted which is very likely not what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @user1594322 , If the firewall only forward it, why will not encrypted? how can I solve this?

Comment: Unless the database servers encrypt their own traffic, the only way to solve this is to use an encrypted tunnel (a VPN tunnel, SSH tunnel, etc).